# Looping through list - looks like it's looping twice

Tags: r

I'm super new to R and am playing around.

I'm interrogating a directory and returning the list of files in the directory to a variable called `files`.  I then am looking to open each file in turn once.  It looks like when I print filename its opening each file twice when I would like only once.  My question is how would I read each file into the variable `met` once?  - once the file is read in I will be eventually doing other stuff with it.

Please see my code below:

```
  strPathToDirectory <- "C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/R/Proj/RawDatabase/"
files <- list.files(strPathToDirectory)
length (files)


for(val in 1:length(files)){
  met <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(paste0(strPathToDirectory,files[val]),colNames=FALSE)
 print(files[val])
}
```

Below is the console output that I get:

```
[1] "2016_Q3.xlsx"
[1] "2016_Q3.xlsx"
[1] "2016_Q4.xlsx"
[1] "2016_Q4.xlsx"
```

As you can see it looks like each file is interrogated twice.

Comment: I don't know why you are seeing the files twice, but your code is probably not doing what you want it to anyway. `met` will only contain the last file, not all of them

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's happening. This sample code does essentially the same after dummy file generation and the output shows each file just once:

```
tmpdir <- tempdir()
for(i in 1:5){
  data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), nrow = 5))
  write.xlsx(data, file = paste(tmpdir, sprintf("file%s.xlsx", i), sep = "/"))
}
files <- list.files(tmpdir, pattern = 'xlsx')

length(files)

for(val in 1:length(files)){
  met <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(paste(tmpdir, files[val], sep = "/"))
  print(files[val])
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1] "file1.xlsx"
[1] "file2.xlsx"
[1] "file3.xlsx"
[1] "file4.xlsx"
[1] "file5.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your problem - have you tried rerunning your code, in case you changed something?
If the `list.files` function still lists each file twice, you can simply use the `unique()`function, to filter out the double entries and then rerun the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Learned that sometimes Visual Studio needs a restart  - not sure why -  but it fixed the problem.